# Parsing out a string that contains two Apostrophe's

Tags: c++, string, parsing, apostrophe

string test = "F'XSXESS'";

How would I go about parsing out F'XSXESS' so that it grabs the information inside the Apostrophe's(XSXESS)?

The output should be XSXESS.

Any idea's on how I should do this?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you basically want to do is, going though all the characters in the string and switch the parsing state at specific events (in your case an encounter of `\'`).
Here a small example:

```
int main() {
    std::string test = "FFF'XSXSXSX'FFFFF";

        std::string result;
        bool state = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
            if(test.at(i) == '\'') {
                state = !state;
                continue;
            }
            if(state)
                result.push_back(test.at(i));
        }
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For the sake of simplicity I've chosen a bool to describe my current state. This code is probably still not the best solution because this would also parse `FF'XX'FFFF'CC'` to `FFCC`.  You could solve this problem by adding an "exit"-state, that indicates the end of the parsing process.
Hope I could help.